# query to output files in sybase ase

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355080/how-to-output-data-from-isql-to-csv-file-with-headings)  , they said we can export data into a file. However they are using ASA( SQLAnywhere ) which is different then ASE, so is there a query similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable;
OUTPUT TO 'C:\temp\sometable.csv' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE ''
```

where we can run it on ASE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must know that "output to" is a command only available in Interactive SQL. (you must run the isql client in order for it to work). Documentation [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/BABDABGE.htm)
The syntaxt for ASE is:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
GO
OUTPUT TO 'C:\temp\sometable.csv' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE ''
```